# Creating a circle in Java

Tags: java, class, geometry

I am trying to create a circle class in Java.
I pasted the first part of the code but I think I may be missing
something in the classes?

```
public class Circle {

    /*
     * Here, you should define private variables that represent the radius and
     * centre of this particular Circle. The radius should be of type double,
     * and the centre should be of type Point.
     */
    private Point A = new Point();
    private double radius;
    // =========================
    // Constructors
    // =========================
    /**
     * Default constructor - performs no initialization.
     */
    public Circle() {
        // This method is complete.
    }

    /**
     * Alternative constructor, which sets the circle up with x and y
     * co-ordinates representing the centre, and a radius. Remember you should
     * not store these x and y co-ordinates explicitly, but instead create a
     * Point to hold them for you.
     *
     * @param xc   x-coordinate of the centre of the circle
     * @param yc   y-coordinate of the centre of the circle
     * @param rad  radius of the circle
     */
    public Circle(double xc, double yc, double rad) {
        Point centre = new Point(xc,yc);
        radius=rad;
    }

    public Circle(Point center, double rad) {

      center = Center;
      radius = Rad;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask? Is your code correct? Compile and run it and see.

Comment: so it's "create a class named circle", not "create a circle"... and what's your problem?

Comment: You are missing lots in your Circle class.  Get your teacher or a tutor to explain how classes are created.  Otherwise, study the Oracle [Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) tutorial.  Study it for days until you completely understand what Oracle is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Your private variable representing the center is named `A` (which is not a good name, why not call it `center`).

In the first constructor you implemented, you are defining a local variable `Point centre` and assign the coordinates to it. Actually you want to assign them to the class variable (I assume that you have renamed it):

```
center = new Point(xc,yc);
```

In the second constructor you try to assign classes to variables which shouldn't compile at all. Also the variables you are assigning to are the arguments and not the class attribute (which have the same names).

You could use:

```
public Circle(Point center, double rad) {

  this.center = center;
  this.radius = rad;
}
```

The `this` tells Java that you are referencing the class variable and not the local variable having the same name.